# Pandas groupby: 3 max per period among multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have these data:

```
                     val1  val2  val3
dt                                   
2017-12-15 00:00:00    81    90    79
2017-12-15 00:01:00    67    85    80
2017-12-15 00:02:00     4    41    37
2017-12-15 00:03:00    61    68    29
2017-12-15 00:04:00    49     6    56
2017-12-15 00:05:00    94    13    93
2017-12-15 00:06:00    91     3    75
2017-12-15 00:07:00    94    81     7
2017-12-15 00:08:00    55    59    33
2017-12-15 00:09:00    97    89    26
2017-12-15 00:10:00    17    75    88
2017-12-15 00:11:00    39    40    96
2017-12-15 00:12:00    61    20    70
2017-12-15 00:13:00    62    31    93
2017-12-15 00:14:00     7    26    29
```

I would like to find the **3 max values for each 5-minute period**.
The max values can be in any column (val1, val2, val3) and must be searched among the 15 values available for the 5 minutes.

At the moment I can only find the largest in a single column. 
**Is it possible to search for nlargest in multiple columns?**

This is the code to generate the data and to search for the max for val1:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_ref = datetime(2017, 12, 15, 0,0,0)
dtime = pd.date_range(date_ref, freq='1min', periods=15)

np.random.seed(seed=1115)
data1 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(dtime))
data2 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(dtime))
data3 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(dtime))

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': dtime, 'val1': data1, 'val2': data2, 'val3': data3})
df.set_index('dt', inplace=True)

print(df)

group = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5min'))

max_only_for_val1 = (pd.DataFrame(
        group["val1"]
        .nlargest(3))
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
    )

print(max_only_for_val1)
```

This is the output:

```
                     val1
dt                       
2017-12-15 00:00:00    81
2017-12-15 00:00:00    67
2017-12-15 00:00:00    61
2017-12-15 00:05:00    97
2017-12-15 00:05:00    94
2017-12-15 00:05:00    94
2017-12-15 00:10:00    62
2017-12-15 00:10:00    61
2017-12-15 00:10:00    39
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't matter where your values come from, let's reshape your data a bit.

```
df = df.reset_index().melt('dt').drop('variable', 1)
df.head(10)

                   dt  value
0 2017-12-15 00:00:00     81
1 2017-12-15 00:01:00     67
2 2017-12-15 00:02:00      4
3 2017-12-15 00:03:00     61
4 2017-12-15 00:04:00     49
5 2017-12-15 00:05:00     94
6 2017-12-15 00:06:00     91
7 2017-12-15 00:07:00     94
8 2017-12-15 00:08:00     55
9 2017-12-15 00:09:00     97
```

Now, call `groupby` + `apply` -

```
def get_max3(x):
    return x.sort_values(ascending=False).head(3)

df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='dt', freq='5min'))['value']\
       .apply(get_max3)\
       .reset_index(0)\
       .reset_index(drop=True)

                   dt  value
0 2017-12-15 00:00:00     90
1 2017-12-15 00:00:00     85
2 2017-12-15 00:00:00     81
3 2017-12-15 00:05:00     97
4 2017-12-15 00:05:00     94
5 2017-12-15 00:05:00     94
6 2017-12-15 00:10:00     96
7 2017-12-15 00:10:00     93
8 2017-12-15 00:10:00     88
```

An alternative definition for `get_max3` using `numpy.sort` -

```
def get_max3(x):
    return np.sort(x.values)[-4::-1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Coldspeed. I didn't know about `melt`.

Comment: @AlexPoca You're welcome. `melt` was actually added as a first order function in version 0.20.

Comment: @AlexPoca Please take a look at my answer once again. I realise my previous answer was not giving you the top 3 for each 5 minute period (it was giving you the top 3 for the first minute of each period only). I've revised my answer now.

Comment: You are right. I was checking my data and trying to find out why changing head(3) to head(4) there were spurious datetimes. Thank you once more!